# Running embedded tomcat java Spring app in linux vm (Microsoft Azure)

Tags: spring, azure, deployment, virtual-machine, war

I have a Spring application that I am trying to run in a linux virtual machine.  I can package the .WAR file and run it locally with no problems on my machine, but I am unable to come up with an understanding on how I would go about running this .WAR file and accessing it externally on a vm as this is my first attempt in doing so.

Right now, I have copied the .WAR file over to the vm, and run `java -jar`cmd through terminal to deploy.  In doing so, my tables are created in my postgres database that is running on the vm.  However, I am not sure how I would go about configuring my endpoint to be able to access my APIs?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You said after running `java -jar` created tables in postgres database, I guess APIs exposed by the app should also be visible

Comment: Yes I think you are correct.  I think the issue might be then to configure to allow external access which I am not too familiar with.  I will do some more digging :) Thanks for your comment!

Comment: okie, you can try curl requests to exposed APIs. The server which hosts these APISs is behind a firewall?

Comment: I have tried to curl requests to the APIs but they are timing out.  I will check firewall settings on server

Comment: Run `tracert <host-name>` on windows machines, `traceroute <host-name>` on *nix machines. To check the port connectivity, you can run `telnet <host-name> <port number on which the app is running>`. traceroute/tracert will let you know if there are any packet drops because of firewall. Also, is there any proxy in between?

Comment: traceroute outputs 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * * etc.. which I am assuming this is a firewall issue?  And no proxy in between

Comment: output is not clear. Can you paste it on https://pastebin.com/ and share the link?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/daP1Cb2n

Comment: Don't think, it should have 30 hops.. Packets are being dropped by firewall.  Are you able to connect using telnet?

Comment: When I attempt to use telnet I get the following: "Connection refused, unable to connect to remote host"

Comment: okies.. Are you able to connect to the remote host using browser? Or able to ping from terminal? Is it on public domain/ private?

Comment: I am unable to connect to the remote host using browser nor can I ping from terminal

Comment: I can't help any more..:) You should speak to your network infra teams. If you can't hit the hostname, can you connect it using resolved ip address?

Comment: If you can't access the remote host, how did you upload the jar and started it?

Comment: No worries mate, I very much appreciate your time.  I used ssh to start jar file which was copied using scp cmd

Comment: Good luck...!!!

Comment: Derp!  Thanks again for your help @harshavmb, my fault.  I had to configure my spring boot application to run on port 80 (it was running on port 8080 previously) and then I had to configure my server to allow http on port 80.  Once again, really appreciate your time!

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed the issue.. Great going..!!! No probs.. always ready to help..

Comment: @Dayna Could you call your API no your VM now?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could configure check VM and app as the following methods.

1.You could use `netstat -ant` to check, please ensure your port 80(your server port) is listening on `0.0.0.0`. If your service is listening on 127.0.0.1. You only could access your API inside the VM.

2.Open port 80 on Azure NSG or  Azure endpoint.

If your VM is ARM VM, you need open port 80 on Azure NSG(Inbound rules). More information about how to add rules on Azure Portal please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-rules). If your VM is classic VM, you need open port 80 on endpoint. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints).

Note: If your APP is listening on 8080 or other ports, you need change 80 to 8080 or others.